# How to decide which EC2 instances to deploy for a cloud application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I'm about to launch my new Cloud application which needs to run on multiple EC2 instances. How should I decide which EC2 instances I need to deploy? How much it depends on the workload? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "which"? Do you mean how many, or what size?

Comment: I have an application which basically, two machines are communicating. I'm not yet sure how complicated these communication will be, but I need to deploy it on EC2 now. I didn't find any clear instruction on how to choose an instance(at lease not on AWS documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are automating the deployment of your infrastructure, you should be able to set up testing infrastructure that you can use to run some load tests where you try to see what will happen with your "expected" production load. This can help identify potential bottlenecks - memory, cpu, IO - something will be the limiting factor on the performance of a single instance.

Then, if you're just about to launch a new application, overprovision - how much and how you accomplish that will depend on how critical it is, how much traffic you expect, what you think the limiting factor on performance might be, and probably a few other variables.  If you determined that CPU might be the limiting factor, then launch with C-class instances, for memory then try R family, and if it's IO then maybe use EBS optimized or provisioned IOPS.

After you have a few days of stats, you can make more reasonable adjustments. Depending on the size of your infrastructure, ensuring you have enough performance at launch probably won't cost you more than a few bucks extra.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your workload.

Start small (or take your best guess), automated everything, monitor loads and then scale up and down as needed.

Comment: Are we able to scale up/down an instance in EC2?

Comment: You can't scale an individual instance, but if you design it right, you can scale your solution, i.e. horizontally instead of vertically.